# How can I enable a custom dictionary with StyleCop.MSBuild version 4.7.48?

Tags: stylecop

After upgrading to the new StyleCop my custom dictionary stopped working like it did with the older version.

I have the following configuration in my solution:

Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise
StyleCop.MSBuild 4.7.48 NuGet package added to the project
In the csproj file I have:

```
<StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>false</StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>
...
<Import Project="..\packages\StyleCop.MSBuild.4.7.54.0\build\StyleCop.MSBuild.Targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\StyleCop.MSBuild.4.7.54.0\build\StyleCop.MSBuild.Targets')" />
```

CustomDictionary.xml and Settings.StyleCop are in the solution root folder
DictionaryFolders set to .\ in Settings.StyleCop

```
<GlobalSettings>
    <CollectionProperty Name="DictionaryFolders">
        <Value>.\</Value>
    </CollectionProperty>
</GlobalSettings>
```

CustomDictionary.xml is added as link in the C# project
CustomDictionary.xml Build Action set to CodeAnalysisDictionary in the C# project

I misspelled a word in a comment and ran build. It gives SA1650 for that error as expected. I added the word to the dictionary and built again but it still complains. I have tried reloading the solution and restarting Visual Studio.

Are there any other configuration steps I am missing to get this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the answer to this. I got it work by using the Rebuild command in Visual Studio instead of Build.